React/JSX-runtime Module not found
Currently working with a React project 17 and after adding the React-Timezone-Select package I've got a build error saying the following :
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Daan\Desktop\Watcherr\hcp-dashboard\node_modules\react\jsx-runtime' imported from C:\Users\Daan\Desktop\Watcherr\hcp-dashboard\node_modules\react-timezone-select\dist\index.js
Did you mean to import "react/jsx-runtime.js"?

(I've added the jsx-runtime package aswell)
The same error is happening aswell whenever I refresh the page where the React-timezone-selector is being used, only after a refresh, I can use the page without breaking it if I don't refresh the page.
Searched online for a long time but nothing seems to work.
Component I made using the TimezoneSelect :
export interface SelectTimeZoneProps {
  timezone: ITimezone,
  setTimezone: (value: ITimezone) => void,
  label: string,
  required?: boolean,
}

const TimezoneSelector: React.FC<SelectTimeZoneProps> = ({
  timezone,
  setTimezone,
  label,
  required,
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {label && <label className={styles.InputLabel}>{label + (required ? "*" : "")}</label>}
      <TimezoneSelect value={timezone} onChange={setTimezone}/>
    </div>
  );
};
export default TimezoneSelector;

and how I use it :
 <div className="row">
        <div className="col-12 col-md-6">
          <TimezoneSelector 
            timezone={selectedTimezone} 
            setTimezone={handleTimeZoneChange} 
            label={t('site-configuration.timezone')}
            required={false}/>
           
        </div>
        <div className="col-12 col-md-6">
          <Alert type={'message'}>
            {t('site-configuration.timezone.explanation')}
          </Alert>
        </div>
      </div>

And If I click on second link of the error msg it brings me to the index of the node_module package of React-timezone-select to this line :
import { jsx } from "react/jsx-runtime";

Has anyone got an idea on how I could fix this?
Many thanks in advance.
